# How to pass in a dynamically allocated array as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

So I created a dynamically allocated array of structs
pretend that structtype is the name of the struct, and arr is the array.

```
structtype * arr;
arr = new structtype[counter+15];
```

Then I attempted to pass that array of structs into multiple types of functions with prototypes such as:

```
void read_info(structtype (&arr)[15], int integer);
```

and

```
void Append(structtype arr[15]);
```

In turn I got these errors:

```
error: cannot convert ‘structtype’ to ‘structtype (&)[15]’
```

and

```
error: cannot convert ‘structtype**’ to ‘structtype (&)[15]'
```

Can yall help me figure out how to get rid of these errors, for example dereferencing the pointer part of the array or something.

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a pointer, because `new` give you a pointer. It can't give you an array, because an array's size must be known at compile time. You need to change your function signatures to take a pointer. But really, you should just use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Don't, just don't. C-style arrays are really bad to work with. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead and use `std::span` if you want your function to be flexible in what it takes as argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is somewhere in memory, location which is pointed by the actual variable `arr` the pointer.

The array is therefore *represented* by the pointer, however the pointer carries no information about where the array ends or its size, unlike std::vector<>.

So you need to pass it with the known size as in:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

struct structtype {
    int a;
};

void dosomething( structtype* s, int size  ) {
    for ( int j=0; j<size; ++j ) {
        printf( "s[%d]=%d\n", j, s[j] );
    }
}

int main() {
    int counter = 50;
    structtype * arr;
    arr = new structtype[counter+15];
    dosomething( arr, counter + 15 );
    delete arr;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/95P5d4sfT

Comment: The **pointer** is just a pointer; it points at the first element **of an array**. But a pointer doesn't carry any size information; you can't get the size of the array given only the pointer.

Comment: That is exactly what I said

Comment: When you do structtype* s, what is the s?

Comment: Oh wait never mind its just the name

Comment: This is a good answer I think, but I'd mention that you can take the size of the array as a template parameter _if_ it's known compile-time.

Comment: @MadFred — no, that’s not what you said. The array is an array. It’s not a pointer. “Your array is just a pointer” obscures that important distinction.

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok I amended the answer, thank you

Comment: @MadFred — well done. +1.